# Is there any way to get the bad record which is causing the issue while sending it to the topic using source connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In sink connector(I am using Jdbc Sink Connector), if I use the following property I will get the bad or error causing record in the mentioned topic(i,e dead_topic).

```
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dead_topic",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 1,
```

Similary is there any way to get it in the mentioned topic while using source connector like SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector?

Comment: What types of errors are you seeing in the source connector? If there was an error serializing a record, then what exactly would you expect in the dead-letter queue?

Comment: I want that record which causes the error. I passes the record as json structure, so if an error has occured with any of the record then I want that record to be sent to a topic or something so that I can get the record which causes the error.

Comment: If you're spooling csv files, then why would it convert anything to json? For example, what if it's the json serializer that failed?

Comment: I'm using spool dir csv source connector to read data from csv files and jdbc sink connector to insert them into database. So while reading data using spool dir, if any data type mismatch occurs (i.e, if a string value come into an integer field) then that record is skipped sincs error.toleranc=all is set. So how can I know that which all records are skipped?

Comment: I would suggest disabling tolerance, and letting the connector fail. Then you can monitor the offset information of the source connector, which should be the line of the CSV that failed. See example here - https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/

Answer (score 0):

The [SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/spooldir/current/connectors/csv_source_connector.html) does not have such a feature.

This particular Connector implements a sort of dead letter queue for files that could not be processed due to errors by moving them to a separate directory where you can inspect/monitor the unprocessed files or where you can set up alternative ingestion/processing mechanisms for those out-of-spec files.

From the [documentation of the connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/spooldir/current/connectors/csv_source_connector.html#file-system):

> **error.path**
>
> The directory to place files that have errors. This
> directory must exist and be writable by the user running Kafka
> Connect.
>
> **Importance**: high Type: string Valid values: Absolute path to a
> directory that exists and is writable.

The most direct way to implement your requirement is to [fork the connector project in github](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) (Apache License 2.0) and implement the Kafka-based dead letter queue yourself.

Comment: Dead letter queues are a feature of all sink connectors only. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#sinkconnectorconfigs_errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name

Answer (score 0):

All **Sink** Connectors offer [Error Reporting](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_errorreporting) by the framework.

For Source connectors such as SpoolDir, the logic is connector specific, so you need to consult its individual config